# How to set json format in ResponseType attribute (asp.net webapi)?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

My controller's actions return IHttpActionResult. In project I use snake_case as json format so I add custom ContractResolver to json settings:

```
JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new SnakeCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
```

And that's how I format response:

```
return new JsonResult<UserInfoModel>(new UserInfoModel(user.UserInfo), JsonSerializerSettings, Encoding.Unicode, this);
```

For autogenerated documentation I add [ResponseType] attribute to methods. But documentation use camelCase format for response exmaples.

**How to set json format in ResponseType attribute?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

Add

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new SnakeCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

To WebApiConfig.cs

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following in global.asax.vb:

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear()
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(New JsonMediaTypeFormatter())

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
```

Comment: No changes.

And I use C# (but this is not so important)